# Program to self check if its running a process or is idle

Tags: vb.net

I would like to know if there is a way for application to check the processes (threads) it is running (self check) and do something with that information. As an example I want to press a button to do something, but if the program is already doing something else I would like to have the option to or not to, run the rest of the procedure behind that button. Hope that makes sense. Im am not running a multithread application so really all I need to know if the main thread is running or if the application is sitting idle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you asking for - you can use the `GetLastInputInfo` API.

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

Dim lastInput As New LASTINPUTINFO()

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> Structure LASTINPUTINFO
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> Public Size As Integer
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> Public Time As Integer
End Structure

<DllImport("user32.dll")> Shared Function GetLastInputInfo(ByRef lii As LASTINPUTINFO) As Boolean
End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Interval = 1000
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    lastInput.Size = Marshal.SizeOf(lastInput)
    lastInput.Time = 0
    GetLastInputInfo(lastInput)
    Label1.Text = Convert.ToInt32((Environment.TickCount - lastInput.Time) / 1000).ToString
    If CInt((Environment.TickCount - lastInputInf.Time) / 1000) > {your amount in sec.} Then  
        Timer1.Stop()
        'run some code when this happens
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```